# android Bitmap caching for ViewPager issue

Tags: android, caching, bitmap, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with ImageView as child views. The ImageView displays Bitmap loaded from network and/or cached to local cache implemented as LruCache based class (from Android support library). The problem is that when the images are removed from LruCache, the GC seems to not release or release too late the bitmap memory. I very often get the exception OutOfMemory while loading new bitmap from network/disk even if the old bitmaps are removed from LruCache and from the holding ImageViews of ViewPager (I removed views from ViewPager). I read that sometimes (?) you must call the Bitmap.recycle (prior to Android 3.0) but this does not work. It also does not work on ICS (I do not call Bitmap.recycle there). 
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector won't recycle your bitmap if something is still referencing it. I would imagine that you have ImageViews hanging onto your bitmaps. ViewPager doesn't recycle Views so you'll need to clear out your ImageView when it's not being shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the BitmapFun sample from android developers [site](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) on how to display Bitmaps efficiently. The sample has a GridView and ViewPager of images already that you can refer to in building your app. Though the sample has some caching [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166616/bitmapfun-sample-has-a-caching-issue) which I did some work around already. You can check it out [here](https://github.com/capecrawler/BitmapFun).

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't handling many images, it's that your images aren't getting deallocated when your activity is destroyed.

It's difficult to say why this is without looking at your code. However, this article has some tips that might help:

http://blog.booking.com/android-reuse-bitmaps.html